# How to add multiple columns in AWS redshift with alter table query

Tags: sql, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Is it possible to add multiple columns in a single Alter query in Redshift

Alter table employee
add column Name,
add column Age,
add column Salary

Answer (score 27, accepted):

According to [Redshift Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_TABLE.html), You can add only one column in each ALTER TABLE statement. Only way to add multiple columns is executing multiple ALTER TABLE statements.

Comment: ....................

Answer (score 0):

We have to use multiple ALTER TABLE statements.

Comment: What does this add to the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66903671/10871073), posted nearly a year ago?